# Bootstrap не работает span

Tags: bootstrap, html, javascript

Знакомлюсь с Bootstrap, и вот столкнулся с проблемой. класс span  не работает .

Вроде сделал всё как надо , и проверил и перепроверил все, но "текст" пишет один под одним всё равно а не разбивает как надо . Помогите разобраться пожалуйста.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      </head>
     <body>

      <div class="container">
       <header>
       <h1>NAME</h1>
       </header>
           <article class="row">
                 <p class="span4"> text</p>
                 <p class="span4"> text2</p>
                 <p class="span4"> text3</p>
           </article>
      </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: <span> надо так ?</span>

Comment: @Shadow33, не, в документации 2.3.2 они вовсю в дивы его суют, так что я не вангомастер.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**span был  в bootstrap 2, в bootstrap 3 сетку основательно переделали.**
Классы разметки, отвечающие за ширину колонок, .span2, .span3 и т.д. заменены на соответствующие .col-md-2, .col-md-3…

Answer (score 2):

В бутстрапе нет класса `span4` or `span`. про разметку читать тут: [Grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).

Comment: спасибо, действительно в документации нет.
как я понял будет правильным 
<p class="col-xs-4"> text</p> 
поправьте если не прав .
спасибо

Comment: Да, понимание правильное! p.s. выше @Fike заметил, что тут важна ещё и мажорная версия бутстрапа, у вас какая?

Comment: 3.0.2 можно сказать только начал разбираться и попал как раз на тему с примером старой версии.